# gb4e roman enumeration format

Tags: numbering, linguistics, gb4e

I'm using the `gb4e` package to enumerate examples in a paper, but in the footnotes I need to enumerate with roman numerals in small letters (i.a), (ii.b), etc. not in small capitals (I.a), (II.a), etc. I have already read that by with `\xlisti` one can do this, but in the compilation it doesn't work, instead it produces roman numerals in small capitals.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please add a small example of code?

Comment: It's not clear to me what format your footnote examples should look like.  What should (i.a) be vs. (ii.b)? This format doesn't make a lot of sense as stated. `gb4e` is quite limited in its customization abilities, so if you only need this in footnotes a regular enumeration using the `enumitem` package might be simpler. But without more information it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not difficult to redefine the footnote example counter to be `\roman`. But the formatting of the subexamples isn't totally clear to me.  The standard way `gb4e` formats them is that the main example is in parentheses and subexamples are in alpha-enumerated lists.  Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thexnumi}{\if@noftnote\@xsi{xnumi}\else\roman{xnumi}\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex An example
\end{exe}
Some text \footnote{These are some examples in a footnote:
\begin{exe}
\ex\begin{xlist}
\ex A footnote subexample
\ex A footnote subexample
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}
\begin{exe}
\ex Another footnote example
\end{exe}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of footnote formatting]